# (iphone) how to force close socket stream?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I use the following code to connect to server and handle events.
almost copy-paste of http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43551

I want to force close the stream before NSStreamEventEndEncountered.
Documentation is lacking and having hard time to figure out how to force close the streams associated with connection. (or close underlying socket if I have to)

Thank you

```
-(void) connectToServerUsingStream:(NSString *)urlStr
                            portNo: (uint) portNo {

    if (![urlStr isEqualToString:@""]) {
        NSURL *website = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
        if (!website) {
            NSLog(@"%@ is not a valid URL");
            return;
        } else {
            [NSStream getStreamsToHostNamed:urlStr
                      port:portNo
                      inputStream:&iStream
                      outputStream:&oStream];
            [iStream retain];
            [oStream retain];

            [iStream setDelegate:self];
            [oStream setDelegate:self];

            [iStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]
                     forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
            [oStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]
                     forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

            [oStream open];
            [iStream open];
        }
    }
}
```

and handles event

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)stream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode {

    NSLog(@"stream event %d", eventCode) ;
    if( stream == iStream ) NSLog(@"on input stream");
    else if( stream == oStream ) NSLog(@"on output stream");
    else NSLog(@"on unknown stream identifier") ;

    switch(eventCode) {
        case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:
            {
                NSLog(@"stream ended; will be closed") ;
                [stream close];
                [stream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]
                        forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
                [stream release];
                stream = nil; // stream is ivar, so reinit it                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

                break;
            }
        case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:
            NSLog(@"stream error") ;
            break ;

        case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
            //TODO: read here                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
            break ;

        case NSStreamEventNone:
            NSLog(@"stream null event") ;
            break ;

        case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
            NSLog(@"stream is now open") ;
            break ;

        case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable:
            //write here                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
            break ;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute the following method on the thread/runloop that the stream was scheduled on:

```
    - (void)closeStream:(NSStream *)stream {
          [stream close];
          [stream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]
                  forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
          [stream release];
          stream = nil;
     }
```

Comment: its the same piece of code as mentioned above. Except for the fact that I have directly used self.inputStream and self.outputStream...   Can usage of self be an issue?

Comment: So, what do you mean by 'does not seem to be working'? Are you synthesizing setters by `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSStream *inputStream`?